# How to generate coordinates in ruby

Tags: ruby, file

So I need to be able to make tons of files, each with a name that consist of xcord-ycord and I need to make engof of these files for there to be one of every combination of the numbers 1-11 (I.E. 1-2 4-5 11-11 1-1 3-7, but not 32-54 42-55 12-12)

Comment: What have you tried so far? The `File` class API is at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/File.html

Comment: Do you need help generating the list of coordinate pairs, or creating the files with those names? You're more likely to get help if you actually ask a question, rather than just describing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Iwassink I need help generating every possible coordinate pair, with the possible numbers in the each value of the coordinate being from 1-11

Comment: @Iwassink I meant 1 to 11, not literally the coordinates 1-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(1..11).to_a.repeated_permutation(2).map{|i,j| "#{i}-#{j}"}
# => ["1-1", "1-2", "1-3", "1-4", "1-5", "1-6", "1-7", "1-8", "1-9", "1-10", "1-11", "2-1", "2-2", "2-3", "2-4", "2-5", "2-6", "2-7", "2-8", "2-9", "2-10", "2-11", "3-1", "3-2", "3-3", "3-4", "3-5", "3-6", "3-7", "3-8", "3-9", "3-10", "3-11", "4-1", "4-2", "4-3", "4-4", "4-5", "4-6", "4-7", "4-8", "4-9", "4-10", "4-11", "5-1", "5-2", "5-3", "5-4", "5-5", "5-6", "5-7", "5-8", "5-9", "5-10", "5-11", "6-1", "6-2", "6-3", "6-4", "6-5", "6-6", "6-7", "6-8", "6-9", "6-10", "6-11", "7-1", "7-2", "7-3", "7-4", "7-5", "7-6", "7-7", "7-8", "7-9", "7-10", "7-11", "8-1", "8-2", "8-3", "8-4", "8-5", "8-6", "8-7", "8-8", "8-9", "8-10", "8-11", "9-1", "9-2", "9-3", "9-4", "9-5", "9-6", "9-7", "9-8", "9-9", "9-10", "9-11", "10-1", "10-2", "10-3", "10-4", "10-5", "10-6", "10-7", "10-8", "10-9", "10-10", "10-11", "11-1", "11-2", "11-3", "11-4", "11-5", "11-6", "11-7", "11-8", "11-9", "11-10", "11-11"]
```